# MouseListener class never called?

Tags: java, user-interface, mouselistener

The `MouseListener` class I have in the segment of code is never being called, regardless of any clicking. I was wondering if I needed anything else in my `Creature` class since only having the listener present is not working out well for me.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Creature 
{
  private static int catchCounter = 0, missCounter = 0;//Used to track the amount of misses and catches
  //----------------------------------------------------
  //Listener class to see if the creature was clicked on
  //----------------------------------------------------
  private class ClickListener implements MouseListener
  {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
    {
      System.out.println("this works");
      if (GamePanel.xContainNeg < event.getX() &&  event.getX() < GamePanel.xContainPos)
      {
        if (GamePanel.yContainNeg < event.getY() && event.getY() < GamePanel.yContainPos)
        {
          catchCounter++;
          if (catchCounter == 10)
          {
            //Ends game if they won
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations! You won!");
            GamePanel.timer.stop();
          }
          else
          {
            //Continues game if not
            GamePanel.timer.restart();
            GamePanel.stats.setText("Catches: " + catchCounter + " \tMisses: " + missCounter);
          }                 
        }
        else 
        {
          missCounter++;
          if (missCounter == 10)
          {
            //Ends game if lost
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You missed 3 times! You lose!");
            GamePanel.timer.stop();
          }
          else
          {
            //continues game if not
            GamePanel.timer.restart();  
            GamePanel.stats.setText("Catches: " + catchCounter + " \tMisses: " + missCounter);
          }
        }
      }
      else 
      {
        missCounter++;
        if (missCounter == 10)
        {
          //ends game if lost
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You missed 3 times! You lose!");
          GamePanel.timer.stop();
        }
        else
        {
          //continues game if not
          GamePanel.timer.restart();
          GamePanel.stats.setText("Catches: " + catchCounter + " \tMisses: " + missCounter);
        }
      }
    }
    //Empty methods
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the listener would ever receive any events?  Just creating a class is not enough.  You must register an instance of the listener class on the component(s) from which you would like that instance to receive events.  You don't present any of that.  Failure to register and registering on the wrong component are by far the most likely reasons for not observing any events.

Answer (score 0):

Is this everything you have? Where is your main method? You never implement your mouse listener to anything, you need a component and add the mouse listener such as if you have a JPanel

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.addMouseListener(//*add mouse listener here*//);
```

Comment: There were 2 other classes along with this. I switched this listener and put it into a Panel class and it still does not work. Where would I put the .addMouseListener() method? In the ClickListener class or in the Panel class?

Comment: Does your Panel class extend JPanel? If so then you would do this.addMouseListener() rather than create a new JPanel object. Once you have that make sure you invoke the mouse listener as well. Can you provide the rest of the code? It'd be much easier to help you